# How to read .txt file to list in a way that words stay as one element in Python?

Tags: python

My .txt file looks like this:

```
9/30/19 [Jamba Juice] $5
10/7/19 [Target] $17
```

How can I convert this to a list in python such that `"Jamba Juice"` stay as one element?
If I use `.split(" ")`, `"Jamba"` and `"Juice"` become two elements in the list. I cannot use `re` library.

```
with open(INPUT_FILE) as bills_file:
    for line in bills_file:
        line = line.strip()
        parts = line.split(" ")
```

Comment: "How can I convert this to a list in python such that "Jamba Juice" stay as one element?" Well, *what is the rule that tells you* that it should? Try to think about the steps that you want the program to take, in detail. Explain a process, in plain English words, that could be followed exactly to get the right result. "I cannot use `re` library." Why not?

Answer (score 0):

Since you know that the first element of the split line is the date and the last element of the split line is the dollar amount, simply join the remaining elements of the split line:

```
with open(INPUT_FILE) as bills_file:
    for line in bills_file:
        line = line.strip()
        parts = line.split(" ")
        date = parts[0]
        cost = parts[-1]
        name = " ".join(parts[1:-1])   # parts[1:-1] selects the first through second-last elements of parts, then we join them with spaces

        parts = [date, name[1:-1], cost] # name[1:-1] selects the fist through second-last characters of name, which removes the brackets
        print(parts)
```

Which gives you the output:

```
['9/30/19', 'Jamba Juice', '$5']
['10/7/19', 'Target', '$17']
```